# Deserialize BSON file in C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, bson

i'm looking to Deserialize BSON file under C++ (Unreal) i already did a link to the bson library ( "libbson" contained on MongoDB library) and i'm able to use it in Unreal, what i'm looking to do now is this (C#) :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "*.bson"))
        {
            byte[] contents =
                File.ReadAllBytes(file);

            Databases cl = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Databases>(contents);
            Console.WriteLine(cl._databases["001"]._date.ToString());
        }
    }

    private class Databases
    {
        public Dictionary<string, SampleClass> _databases;
    }
```

in C++, any help?

Comment: You'll want to find a library that offers that feature, and library recommendations are beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: since the library that i need is "libbson" that is a part of "MongoDB" and there is a lot of questions about using MongoDB and it's library in StackOverflow i don't understand your message sorry ( as i wrote i already have that library imported into my project)

Comment: Oh, if your question is how to correctly use a specific library, then that's absolutely fine. However, your question as written does not mention MongoDB or libbson. There are many bson-compatible libraries available in C++, and without you specifying one, there's no way to know.

Comment: i'm sorry, i was pretty sure that i had specified "libbson" and "MOngoDB" my fault, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a C++ library which can be found here:

http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/

For further information on how to work with BSON, using C++, please refer to the documentation provided here:

http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/working-with-bson/